# Find a basis for $U \subset \mathbb{C}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^4$ be the subspace $U = \{(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) \in \mathbb{C}^4: z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4 = 0$ and $z_1 = iz_2 \}$.

So far this is all I have.

a) The dimension of $U$ is 2 so there must be two basis vectors.

Looking at the system of linear equations, I observe

$$\begin{align*}z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4 &= 0 \\ z_1 - iz_2 &= 0 \end{align*}$$

Then $z_1 = iz_2$ and I replace $z_1$ in the first equation to get $(i+1)z_2 + z_3 + z_4 = 0$. However I am not sure how to get the basis vectors from this part...

Comment: scale so $z_2=1$; what is $z_1$ then?  what could $z_3$ and $z_4$ be?

Comment: I believe $z_3$ and $z_4$ are supposed to be "free variables" because there are more variables than equations, but I am not sure how to represent them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system has as augmented matrix the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&1&0 \\ 1&-i&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and its reduced row echelon form is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&\tfrac12(1+i)&\tfrac12(1+i)&0 \\ 0&1&\tfrac12(1-i)&\tfrac12(1-i)&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
which means $z_1=-\tfrac12(1+i)(z_3+z_4)$ and $z_2=-\tfrac12(1-i)(z_3+z_4)$. Then, $U$ can be written as
$$U=\left\{ 
\big( -\tfrac12(1+i)(z_3+z_4),-\tfrac12(1-i)(z_3+z_4),z_3,z_4 \big) :\, z_3,z_4\in \Bbb C\right\}$$